# Tastypie annotation error "empty attribute..."

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I'm using tastypie to create an API and I'm stuck trying to annotate a Sum total of decimals over a certain type. Each transaction has an associated bucket type and I'd like to group by bucket type, and sum the transactions.

api resource

```
class TransactionTotalResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = TTransaction.objects.values('bucket').annotate(bucket_total=Sum('amount'))   
        resource_name = 'transaction_total'
        include_resource_uri = False
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        authorization= Authorization()
```

model

```
class TTransaction(models.Model):
    bucket = models.ForeignKey(TBucket)
    date = models.DateField()
    transaction_type_id = models.IntegerField()
    amount = models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=18, decimal_places=2, blank=True)
    account_id = models.IntegerField()
    recurrence_flag = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True)
    notes = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=100)
    paid = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True)
    is_credit = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True)
    reconciled = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True)
    active = models.SmallIntegerField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = u't_transaction'
        ordering = ['-date']
```

if I run it from the terminal, it works.

```
from django.db.models import Sum
TTransaction.objects.values('bucket').annotate(bucket_total=Sum('amount'))

[{'bucket': 10, 'bucket_total': Decimal('35.24')}, {'bucket': 2, 'bucket_total': Decimal('62.00')}]
```

However, hitting the transaction_total URL for this and I get

```
{"error": "The object '{'bucket': 10, 'bucket_total': Decimal('35.24')}' has an empty attribute 'account_id' and doesn't allow a default or null value."}
```

If I set all the model fields to be "null=True", then I get a different error:

```
{"error_message": "invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''", "traceback" ...
```

Is there a way to get tastypie to work with the annotaion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I would answer this since I found a way to do it in the dehydrate method:

```
def dehydrate(self, bundle):
    transaction = TTransaction.objects.filter(bucket_id=bundle.data['id']).values('bucket').order_by('bucket').annotate(Sum('amount'))
    bundle.data['transaction_total'] = transaction
    return bundle
```